# How to use getFilesDir()?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am trying to get my app's root directory, but getting the following exception. I even defined my context. How do I fix this? I have been stuck on this since the past 3 hours.

```
   ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(this);
   String FileDirectory =  c.getFilesDir().getPath();
```

exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getFilesDir()' on a null object reference
```

edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(this);

File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
String FileDirectory =  c.getFilesDir().getPath();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: I think is your `c` value is null.

Comment: Can you put more code. Where you call `new ContextWrapper(this)`. By where i want said in what class.

Comment: @crammeur I posted it. Also I tried displaying the value in a toast and it works perfectly fine

Comment: @crammeur I just want to use `getFilesDir()` instead of `File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);` and I am unable to figure out how to do it

Answer (score 2):

You can't make those calls at creation time.  The context is not valid until after super.onCreate() has been called.  Move all of that code into onCreate and it should be ok.  Although making a ContextWrapper is kind of a waste-  an Activity is a Context, just call getFilesDir directly on this.

Comment: you are telling me to move my context and the string in my onCreate?

Comment: You can declare them outside, but setting their value must be done in onCreate (or later) after super.onCreate is called.